# getting the whole output from shell_exec when running composer install

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the whole output that running this command 'composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist' should generate

When I run this command in the shell this is the output:

Loading composer repositories with package information

> Installing dependencies from lock file
>
> Nothing to install or update
>
> Generating autoload files
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
>
> php artisan optimize
>
> Generating optimized class loader

when I run the same command from php code:

> echo "
> composer: " . shell_exec('cd .. ; composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist');

All I get is:
Generating optimized class loader

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shell_exec` captures the output written to `stdout`. Composer writes most of its messages to `stderr`, not `stdout`. The "Generating optimized class loader" comes from Laravel's artisan command, which writes to `stdout`, which is why you see that message.

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` if you want to get all the output from `shell_exec`. Add `2>&1` to the end of your command to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

```
echo "composer: " . shell_exec('cd .. ; composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist 2>&1');
```